# Why we take transpose of Vector (Displacement Vector)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, computer-science, vectors, image-processing

I'm trying to understand some equations that involves transpose of vectors (displacement vectors to be precise)

Two set of vectors F and G (with i,j) that corresponds to X,Y value in plane

[image: F and G Vectors]

and Final Displacement Vectors set U is calculated like this

[image: Displacement Vectors]

[image: U i,j]

I'm unable to understand this T in equation ? Is it Transpose ? If its transpose why we are using it, how transpose is helping us? How its calculated ? Can anyone tell me

Comment: Yes, it is the transposed vector and it is '*calculated*' by turning your head 90 degrees. You usually use this to save space when writing it down. You can rewrite a column vector as a transposed row vector and vice versa..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same as column vector. To save space its written as Tranposed row vector